# What is the appropriate way to use a single session when using BigQuery ODBC with excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I would like to use excel to run a BigQuery multi-statement query that may be heavy, only once, with other queries pulling from temp tables created during that session. It seems despite the enabling sessions in the ODBC setting area, that this does not work...

Any advice to configure this correctly?

Example: Sheet 1 runs a query that creates Temp tables 1,2,3 etc [Heavy query]
Sheet 2 runs a query that is light weight, using those temp tables
Sheet 3 runs a query that is light weight, using those temp tables
etc.

Bonus: Is sessions possible in connected sheets? So multiple sheets do not need to run repetitive queries.